# How to run the function inside Observable.create everytime when it is called

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm very new to RXJava.
I have a function called `politelyrefresh()` that concats two observables together, but the functions in these two observables only run the first time I called `politeRefresh`, I'm not sure this is the right way to do it. What I want is run this function inside the observables everytime.

```
public void politelyRefresh() {
    Observable.concat(refreshStoreDataObservable, refreshProjectDataObservable)
            .finallyDo(()-> {
                try {     
                 //someother other long runnning-network requests

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "politelyRefresh finallyDo Error", e);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(reloadUiFromLocalStorageSubscriber);

}
```

//the other observable is pretty much the same but making another request

```
Observable<String> refreshStoreDataObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

  //DOESN'T GET HERE SECOND TIME!

        Store.syncStores(new ListCallback() {
            @Override
            public void syncSuccess() {
                getSyncStateManager().setStoresRefreshed();
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void syncError() {

                subscriber.onError(new Throwable("SYNC STORES ERROR"));
                getSyncStateManager().setStoresSyncCompleted();
            }
        });

    }
});
Subscriber<String> reloadUiFromLocalStorageSubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        if (mStoreRefreshLayout != null){
            mStoreRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "reloadUiFromLocalStorageSubscriber: onError", e);
        if (mStoreRefreshLayout != null){
            mStoreRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "reloadUiFromLocalStorageSubscriber: onNext " + s);
    }
};
```

Comment: Subscribers are not reusable. Once they terminated, subscribing them again will immediately cancel the sequence.

Comment: When would you like the code in the ```OnSubscribe``` to be run again? Every time you attach it to the ```reloadUiFromLocalStorageSubscriber```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by move the subscriber from an class instance to inside the .subscribe() function(). I have no idea why this is happening.

```
Observable.concat(refreshStoreDataObservable, refreshProjectDataObservable)
        .finallyDo(()-> {
            try {     
             //someother other long runnning-network requests

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "politelyRefresh finallyDo Error", e);
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe( new Subscriber<String>() { /*rest of code  */}); //**here
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`Observable.defer()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html). What this basically does is *defer* the creation of the Observable to when it is being subscribed to.

Here's a quick example:

```
public class Refresher {

    Refresher() {
        politelyRefresh();
        politelyRefresh();
    }

    public void politelyRefresh() {
        Observable.defer(() -> Observable.concat(refreshProjectData(), refreshStoreData()))
                .map(this::processData)
                .subscribe(this::printData);
    }

    private Observable<String> refreshStoreData() {
        System.out.println("StoreData Refreshed");
        return Observable.just("data1","data2","data3");
    }

    private Observable<String> refreshProjectData() {
        System.out.println("ProjectData Refreshed");
        return Observable.just("Project1","Project2", "Project3");
    }

    private String processData(String data) {
        return data + " processed";
    }

    private void printData(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}
```

If you instantiate our refresher object, you'll get

```
StoreData Refreshed
StoreData Refreshed
Project1 processed
Project2 processed
Project3 processed
data1 processed
data2 processed
data3 processed
StoreData Refreshed
StoreData Refreshed
Project1 processed
Project2 processed
Project3 processed
data1 processed
data2 processed
data3 processed
```

If you'd like something to run on a different thread, you'd specify that on the specific observable you're looking to run on a non-ui thread.

So, for example, you might want to run the Observable in politelyRefresh on a background thread and subscribe to it on the UI thread. The creation of the other Observables will happen in a background thread too!

Comment: wouldn't this Observable run itself on the background thread?

Comment: I tried your code with the Observable.def(()->Observable.concat() ),  it works same as the just Observable.concat(). But when I changed to my code, this defer thing doesn't work..

Comment: I found out if subscriber.onCompleted() is called in the observable.create callback, calling the function won't run again. How do I solve this?

Comment: Notice how I have a method which creates a new observable in the ```concat``` - that's the key to having that code run again. And no, as it stands this will run on the thread it is called on.